# AWS PHP SDK Signature V4

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the following code to generate my signature for a direct to S3 upload (using sig v4 because the bucket is in Frankfurt):

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key' => Configure::read('Aws.key'), 
            'secret' => Configure::read('Aws.secret'), 
            'region' => Configure::read('Aws.region'),
            'signature' => 'v4'
        )
    );


    $postObject = new \Aws\S3\Model\PostObject($s3, Configure::read('Aws.bucket'), 
                                               array('acl' => 'public-read'));


    $form = $postObject->prepareData()->getFormInputs();

    $this->set('policy', $form['policy']);
    $this->set('signature', $form['signature']);
```

However, the end result of a POST is always an XML response containing this message:

```
 The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Switched back to Ireland for now. However I am going to solve this and come back with an answer.

Comment: I just wrote an article on this, except I didn't use AWS package, instead built the policy and signature straight - but it does work with signature V4 (and Frankfurt region) http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/direct-upload-to-s3-using-aws-signature-v4-php/ (ps sorry for self promotion)

Comment: @EddTurtle that is a nice tutorial regarding v4 signatures in s3, one quick question regarding what type of operations can be done with v4 signatures like upload, download and delete? u have given only for upload and is there any other ways to implement v4 signatures via laravel?